# AWS S3 Listing API - How to list everything inside S3 Bucket with specific prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to list all items with specific `prefix` in S3 bucket. Here is directory structure that I have:

```
Item1/
     Item2/
          Item3/
               Item4/
                     image_1.jpg
               Item5/
                     image_1.jpg
                     image_2.jpg
```

When I set `prefex` to be `Item1/Item2`, I get as a result following keys:

```
Item1/Item2/
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item4/image_1.jpg
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item5/image_1.jpg
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item5/image_2.jpg
```

What I would like to get is:

```
Item1/Item2/
Item1/Item2/Item3
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item4
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item5
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item4/image_1.jpg
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item5/image_1.jpg
Item1/Item2/Item3/Item5/image_2.jpg
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in golang?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3#example-S3-ListObjects-Shared00 - Sample for GO SDK

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Can you show your code?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you for your help. Yes, I have tried using Listing API to list all keys with specific prefix (result of what I gett and what I was expecting is showed in the question). John has explained it nicely why I cannot get result that I desire. I managed to get the result by string manipulation when I retrieved all of the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. It is a flat object storage system.

For example, using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) I could copy a command to an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This work just fine, even though `folder1` and `folder2` do not exist. This is because objects are stored with a `Key` (filename) that **includes the full path of the object**. So, the above object actually has a Key (filename) of:

```
folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

However, to make things easier for humans, the Amazon S3 management console makes it *appear* as though there are folders. In S3, these are called **Common Prefixes** rather than folders.

So, when you make an API call to list the contents of the bucket while specifying a `Prefix`, it simply says "List all objects whose Key starts with this string".

Your listing doesn't show any folders because they don't actually exist.

Now, just to contradict myself, it actually *is* possible to create a folder (eg by clicking *Create folder* in the management console). This actually **creates a zero-length object with the same name as the folder**. The folder will then appear in listings because it is actually listing the zero-length object rather than the folder.

This is probably why `Item1/Item2/` appears in your listing, but `Item1/Item2/Item3` does not. Somebody, at some stage, must have "created a folder" called `Item1/Item2/`, which actually created a zero-length object with that Key.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification! I've managed to get desired result by performing string manipulation (spliting strings etc.) on bucket keys.